# Google event listings - change date . time

Tags: google, google-search

We have recently taken over a festival website and noticed that Google appears to be picking up dates and start times for the event and displaying at the top of search results - this is great for promo but the time is incorrect and we arent sure how to change it - can anyone advise where it is getting this data from and how we might go about changing it change?

Answer (score 2):

Does your website use schema? That is more often than not where Google would be getting the information to include in the snippet. In some cases, Google gets the info from another website (for instance, if you use a third party to list the event or get registrations). Assuming it is your website, here is Google's help article about event markup with how you can include event dates and times. I'd check your code to see if you have anything like this and then you could fix from there. https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/events

Comment: It is often very likely that the event data is coming from another site that has more authority than the original site. When this happens, there is little to do. Google often uses these larger sites as an authority simply because of the wealth of formatted data. Smaller sites will have trouble with more accurate data showing up in the SERPs without obtaining more authority. A sites authority is the key.

Comment: Thanks guys - our SEO guy is offsite today - i'll check with him re Schema